# the Samsung Galaxy Note II dips or devicePixelRation

Tags: mobile, galaxy, samsung-mobile

The resolution of the Samsun Galaxy Note II is `1280*720`, but I don't know what the `devicePixelRation` or `device-independent pixels`.

Someone say the dips is **320px**, and others say **360px**. What is the exact value?

Answer (score 1):

This is my first reply, hope I give the right answer as you want... @@

By the wiki definition：[Calculation of monitor PPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density)

Dp = sqrt(Wp*Wp+Hp*Hp)

where

- Dp is diagonal resolution in pixels
- Wp is width resolution in pixels   (in Note2 is 720px)
- Hp is height resolution in pixels  (in Note2 is 1280px)

and

PPI = (Dp / Di)

- Di is diagonal size in inches (this is the number advertised as the size of the display) (in Note2 is 5.55inch)

So your can get your dp = sqrt(720*720+1280*1280) = 1468.60

your PPI(not always the same as DPI, but in our situation you can consider they are the same)  PPI = (1468.60 / 5.55) = 264 (physically), such should locate at hdpi...

The Ratio should be 264/160 = 1.65, the device-independent pixels on width should be (720/1.65) = 436.36 dip (& on height=>775.76 dip)

You mentioned that someone say the dips is 320px, I think they means the DPI is 320 or 360... In the formula the DPI is 264(physically)...

What I saw on [XDA-Developer Said](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2243799)：

> DPI is the pixel density of your screen that can be soft-modded to make your display "look" different. There are many apps that can actually change your DPI. Note 2's DPI is 320 by default. 240 DPI is the best one IMO for this type of screen size.

Hope this answer can help you...